# Screen Tearing Nvidia GT640m

Tags: nvidia, screen, intel, gpu, xserver

I want to use my Nvidia card on my computer rather than intel hd4000. However it has a outstanding amount of tearing both vertical and horizontal, even there is god damn triangles appearing in video playbacks. Is there any way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers + Optimus support.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

In case you still have issues uninstall the current stable NVIDIA drivers.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

After the restart install the (most recent) latest official NVIDIA drivers.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Switch between graphics from NVIDIA X Server Settings PRIME Profiles.

Comment: I have tried all of the drivers as well as ppa,. No luck. For instance the device doesn't recognize the screens properly and shows one screen 3560x1080 instead of one 1600x900 and one 1920x1080. There is no vsync option under x server settings as well. The intel chip works enourmously but it's not strong enought. I changed my OS to Windows and dual booting a small ssd with ubuntu inside till i solve the issue. Any other tip?

Comment: @biozalp : Sorry unfortunately not really ... maybe the next drivers version will have this issue fixed. NVIDIA continuously improves the drivers and soon after a new release they are available in the GPU drivers PPA. :)

Comment: Been waiting since 2012 maybe new year will bring it's luck (no luck at all)

Comment: @biozalp : Maybe you should consider to replace the GPU (if this is possible) - the GEFORCE 600 series is known for not being the best NVIDIA chip, many users are having problems with this special card. Hope I nevertheless could help you a little bit ! :)

Comment: I wouldn't mess around with my laptop. I'm going to build a new system max 1 year later , 980ti awaits me :) Thank you for your time

Comment: My older laptop with GT630M and HD4000 screen tearing was fixed with options in Xorg configuration.